# ListBox populating selected values on loading

Tags: angular, listbox, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, populate

I'm using list box in reactive forms in angular. I'm able to get the multiple selected values while adding. While editing, need to populate the value in the list box, so that user can select different values. I can't use ngModel in reactive forms, as it's deprecated. Any idea on how to populate value on loading. It will have multiple values which need to displayed as selected on loading.

I'm using angular 13.0 and primeng "13.0.3". Here is my HTML

```
<p-listbox [options]="contacts" optionLabel="contact_role_name"
[listStyle]="{'max-height':'75px', 'max-width':'300px'}" (onChange)="getSelectedRoles($event)"
[multiple]=multi formControlName="roleName">
</p-listbox>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To populate value within the listbox, you simply have to set value of the form control associated with it, in your case `roleName`.

Depending upon what moment of time do you have data to be populated available, you can either define the form control with the initial form state or use `setValue` to set it's value at a later time.

Looking at the html code shared, the value would be something as:

```ts
// An array of objects
valueToPopulate = [
    {contact_role_name: 'some role 1', someProperty: 'some property value 1'},
    {contact_role_name: 'some role 5', someProperty: 'some property value 5'}
]
```

Once you have the value available, you can simply use `setValue` as:

```ts
// You need to get hold of roleName form control
// How you do it, depends upon your implementation
const roleNameControl = this.yourForm.get('roleName');

// set value
roleNameControl.setValue(valueToPopulate);
```

You can read more here: [Updating parts of the data model](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model)